# How to import a SharePoint table to SAS?

Tags: sharepoint, sas

I have a link in the SharePoint for the table which I want to import using SAS, but how to do that ?

This is my direct link to the SharePoint table:
http://teamsites.companywent.net/sites/0000000007/PCO/FAO/Lists/list%20of%202016/Default_2012_1.aspx

Answer (score 0):

SAS works with SAS data sets. To work with data that is not in an SAS data set, you'll need to first import it.

At the time of this post, [the SAS documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/webeditorug/68254/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p11uw39h8jb27on1fc3d0og7ac52.htm) indicates that only the following types of data files can be imported:

> - Microsoft Access database files
> - Delimited files
> - dBASE 5.0, IV, III+, and III
> - Stata files
> - Microsoft Excel files
> - JMP files
> - Paradox DB files
> - SPSS files
> - Lotus 1-2-3 files from Releases 2, 3, 4, or 5

When importing a data file, the data file may first need to be uploaded to SAS Studio, and you cannot import remote files (i.e. as files available through FTP shortcuts).

Since SharePoint lists are not files, you can't import them directly into SAS. However, you could export a SharePoint list to Excel (using SharePoint's web-based interface) and save the resulting file in .XLSX format.

You can then import that Excel file into SAS following the instructions for [importing an Excel worksheet](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/webeditorug/68254/HTML/default/p11uw39h8jb27on1fc3d0og7ac52.htm#p1bwix5r1uxis8n1o6nlaqmwmk6o).

> 1. Click **Server Files and Folders** in the navigation pane and browse to find the file that you want to import.
> 2. Right-click the file that you want to import and select **Import Data**. The top of the **Import Data** tab shows the name and location of this Excel file. It also shows several options that you can customize.
> 3. To import the data from a specific worksheet, enter the name of that worksheet in the **Worksheet name** box. By default, SAS Studio imports the data from the first worksheet.
> 4. To specify the location to save the output data set, click **Change**. By default, the output data set is saved to the Work library, which is a temporary location. The contents in this library are deleted when you exit SAS Studio.
> 5. To generate SAS variable names from the data values in the first row of the worksheet, select **Generate SAS variable names**. If a data value in the first row in the input file is read and it contains special characters that are not valid in a SAS name, such as a blank, then SAS converts the character to an underscore.
> 6. To import the Excel worksheet, click [running person icon]